# No bullet with empty item in Pandoc and Beamer

Tags: beamer, pandoc, markdown

I'm currently trying to switch from Powerpoint to using markdown and Pandoc to create my slides by means of Beamer.

In Powerpoint I can add an empty line to a bullet-list and Powerpint then automatically hides the bullet. I use that often to create some extra space between entries. If I use empty items in markdown I get a bullet in front of an empty line which is not what I want:

[image]

Is there a way to e.g. change the Latex template of Pandoc in a way so that the bullets in front of an empty line are hidden automatically?

Best regards...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\bigskip`:

```
- bla
  - bla
  - bla
- bla
  - bla
  - bla
    \bigskip
- bla
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `\emptyitem` command, which insert a vertical space in your list.

```
\newcommand{\emptyitem}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}
```

You can play with the argument of the `\vspace` command to change the height of the vertical space.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\emptyitem}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item xxx
        \begin{itemize}
            \item xxx
            \emptyitem
        \end{itemize}
        \item xxx
        \begin{itemize}
            \item xxx
            \emptyitem
        \end{itemize}
        \item xxx
        \begin{itemize}
            \item xxx
            \emptyitem
        \end{itemize}    
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```